# Query Attributes - Model Builder ArcGIS

Tags: python, attributes, arcgis

I'm trying to build a Model that selects points (stores) from a point shapefile that are within a polygon shapefile (block groups) and then assigns the the name attribute (Block Group ID) of that specific polygon to a new field in the points shapefile. Since I have a lot of points and a lot of polygons, I have made the process iterative meaning that the model will cycle through the total list of polygons and find any points located within a certain polygon to assign the name to the point shapefile's new field.

So far I have been able to select the a polygon and select the points within that polygon. I'm trying to find a way to write the name of that polygon to the new field in the points associated with it.

This is a screenshot of what I have so far:

http://i67.tinypic.com/qqv0y9.jpg

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach to consider is doing a *Spatial Join*.

Spatial Join (Analysis)
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000000q000000

You could also perform a *Join based on Location*
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//005s0000002n000000

Comment: Although this could be a useful answer, links may get broken over time. Could you please copy-paste the most relevant parts into your post? Thanks!

Comment: The most relevant part in this case is knowing the name of the process (see italicized), as the process will vary to some extent based on what version of the software is used (which the original posted did not mention).  The links posted are specific to ArcGIS version 10.2, but can provide a broad view of what can be done.  It will be incumbent, however, on the user to look up the process specifics for the version of ArcGIS they are actually using (and there are many).  I'd suggest looking it up using a Google search based on the process name and the software version.